# Keeping reference to the correct storyboard

Tags: ios, ios6, storyboard, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have an issue where I try and instantiate a view controller and get an error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

The error is caused by having an incorrect reference to the storyboard. I.e. `self.storyboard` is not returning what I expect it to return.

I have an NSobject subclass setup that I use for some class methods, I have a method setup like this to return the storyboard:

```
+(UIStoryboard *)storyboardName {
    NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
    if ([self isPad]) {
        storyboardName = [storyboardName stringByAppendingString:@"_iPad"];
    } else {
        storyboardName = [storyboardName stringByAppendingString:@"_iPhone"];
    }
    return [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
}
```

## Question

My question is would this be the correct way to handle this? Then call [MyObject storyboardName] to return the correct storyboard.

OR

Is there a way to keep the correct reference to the storyboard through the application. Or find out why `self.storyboard` is not returning the expected storyboard?

The correct storyboard is setup in the General > Main interface application setting. There is no AppDelegate adding the storyboard/window work etc. The app simply loads the main interface storyboard and the initial view controller as expected.

Comment: Maybe return [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil]; this returns you nil. Put if() block there and see when it's happening - maybe you have some typo.

Comment: No, my method works fine. That returns the storyboard name as expected. The issue is that everytime I need a reference to self.storyboard I have to run this method to return the correct storyboard. I thought there would be a better way to keep reference through out the app

Comment: Why do you need storyboard reference anyways ? :)

Comment: For ...[self.storyboard instaniateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"" animated:NO; completion:nil]; ... etc

Comment: Oh I see. Than this will be best way to approach the problem - there is no way to reference it through appdelegate or anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks, ill leave open for bit to see if anyone suggests anything else. thanks again

Comment: You shouldn't really have to have a storyBoard method on every object for this. I would assume you keep a property in the app delegate with a storyboard reference. But you have to make sure it's a full strong property or it will get released. What is the code you tried using when you did it that way instead and which part of it is triggering the nil object error?

Comment: What is the disadvantage with using this method? I have not set this up in the AppDelegate way you mention, the error occurs when trying to use the self.storyboard reference which is available from a View Controller. Can you confirm your approach in an answer please?